# Bluetooth connection with arduino uno

Tags: java, android-studio, bluetooth

I'm trying to build an app that connects to an arduino board using bluetooth. I have managed to turn on bluetooth, get paired devices but the function for connecting to the device using mmsocket.connect() is not working on the client side.I'm trying to make it work without creating a socket on the server side if its possible.If its not possible, can anyone tell me how to create a server socket on an arduino uno board?

Comment: what type of bluetooth do you have in your arduino? classic or low energy?

Comment: I do not know yet. so far I only know its an arduino, its for a project. what is preferred though? classic or low energy? I only want the arduino to only receive data.

Comment: You must know though. Because in Android; BLE and classic use different APIs and ways to communicate each other. Hence you cannot use the `mmsocket.connect()` method for BLE type. It must be implemented using `BluetoothGattCallback` interface. That's why no one can help if you don't know what the type of bluetooth is.